# Is there an efficient algorithm to decide whether a number is pseudoperfect?

Tags: number-theory, divisor-sum

A pseudoperfect number (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PseudoperfectNumber.html) is a positive integer that can be written as a sum of distinct proper divisors of it.

So, to decide whether a number $n$ is pseudoperfect, we have to decide whether a subset of the set of proper divisors of $n$ has sum $n$. The subset-problem is NP-complete in general. If the number of divisors is very high, brute force will not be feasible.

> Is there an efficient algorithm to decide whether $n$ is pseudoperfect , assuming that the prime factorization of $n$ is known ?

Comment: Thoughts: (1) Equivalent to determining whether a number is weird (abundant but not equal to the sum of any subset of its proper factors). (2) Probably an algorithm for determining pseudoperfectness would rely on prime-factoring the number, which itself is difficult in general.

Comment: @paw88789 OK, I will edit the question to add that it is assumed that the prime factorization is known.

Comment: Well, on the page linked it says this is just as hard as the (general) subset sum problem , though no direct explanation is given afaik.